# Access LPT in C++

Tags: c++, windows, lpt

How to access LPT port in C++ visual express? I've read about including io.dll but I don't know how to use it. Could someone show me a simple code for doing it?

Comment: Use inpout32.dll to bypass the I/O restrictions.  Take the first google hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CreateFile() to open an I/O device such as a printer port.

```
hLPT = CreateFile(
    "LPT1",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    0);

WriteFile(
    hLPT,
    pointerToBuffer,
    sizeOfBuffer,
    &numberOfBytesWritten,
    NULL);

FlushFileBuffers(hLPT);
```